# Pagination of records from MySQL Database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a script that counts how many records it sees on the page :

```
   <script>
document.write(document.getElementById('moon').rows.length-1);
document.write ('&nbsp;');
document.write (' of ');
document.write ('&nbsp;');
document.write(document.getElementById('moon').rows.length-1);
document.write (' pages');

 </script>
```

How would I use this to paginate 10 records at a time? 
Perhaps using a styling such as `display:none` or something and then linking to these hidden divs on the "page" count.

Thanks

**Edit:**

I have tried to use a PHP Mysql Query to do this with num_rows, but it always throws out errors even when I am getting data!

**2nd EDIT**

Ok, I am pulling the information and displaying it with:

```
<table class="std" id="moon" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <?php

        $pcounter = 1;
        $userID = LedDB::getInstance()->get_user_id_by_name($_SESSION['user']);
        $presult = LedDB::getInstance()->get_page_by_campaign_id($campaignID);
        $i=0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($presult)):
             $style = "";
                if($i%2==0)
{
    $style = 'style="background-color: #EFEFEF"';
}
echo "<tr ".$style.">";     
            echo "<td class='camp' style='padding-left:10px;'><b><a href='editPage.php?pageID=" .htmlentities($row['pid']) ."&campaignID=" .htmlentities($row['campaignid']) ."' class='camp'> Page" . $pcounter . "</a></b></td>";
            echo "<td style='padding-left:10px;'></td>";
            echo "<td style='padding-left:10px;'></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            $pageID = $row['pid'];
            //The loop is left open
            ?>
            <td>
             <div class="buttons">
                <form name="editPage" action="editPage.php" method="GET"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="campaignID" value="<?php echo $campaignID ?>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="pageID" value="<?php echo $pageID ?>"/>
                    <button type="submit" name="editPage" value="Edit" class="blue" >
                   <img src="images/edit.png" width="20" height="20"></button>

                </form>
                 </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form name="deletePage" action="deletePage.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pageID" value="<?php echo $pageID; ?>"/>
                    <div class="buttons">
                    <button type="submit" name="deletePage" value="Delete" class="negative">
                    <img src="images/delete_x.png" width="20" height="20"></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
            <?php
            echo "</tr>\n";
        $pcounter++;
        $i++;
        endwhile;
        mysqli_free_result($presult);
        ?>
    </table>
```

Where `$presult = LedDB::getInstance()->get_page_by_campaign_id($campaignID);` is this:

```
public function get_page_by_campaign_id($campaignID) {
     $campaignID = $this->real_escape_string($campaignID);
    return $this->query("SELECT pid,campaignid,message_text,message FROM pages WHERE campaignid =" . $campaignID );
}
```

Whenever I try to wrap this in a pagination class, it either returns a 0 value or just bombs out my entire script with `sql_num_rows()` errors...

That is the reason I thought javascript pagination would be the best solution in this case.

Comment: So fix the errors. Pagination *should* happen at the database. The rest is just presentation.

Comment: Pro tip: Use LIMIT on your PHP mysql query

Comment: I have limited the query to 10 :
`SELECT pid,campaignid,message_text,message FROM pages WHERE campaignid =" . $campaignID . " DESC LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several examples on the web to get you started, thats where I'd start:

http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=pagination&x=0&y=0&go_search=1
http://www.phpsnaps.com/snaps/view/php-pagination-class/
http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10283679
http://phpsense.com/2007/php-pagination-script/